# any android launcher that uses motion gestures, those read with gyroscope / accelerometer?

Tags: android, launcher

There're plenty of launchers that allow to start apps etc. using gestures drawn on the touchscreen.

Samsung also uses something they call air gestures - waving hands captured with the camera?

But for some reason I cannot find any apps using gestures drawn with the phone itself in the air to launch apps etc.

Not even primitive

This is unexpected, given any simple gyroscope/accelerometer test shows that the phone can discern between various phone movements and tilts

Does anyone know of any apps that I'm just missing?

Thanks!